# Windows Emacs Keybinding

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I know this is not a Windows site, so my apologies. I use Ubuntu all day, every day, and have finally convinced my buddy to try it. He is on Windows 7, so we installed [this](http://www.ourcomments.org/cgi-bin/emacsw32-dl-latest.pl). It seems to be working great, but when he hits C-p ( prev. line ) it is trying to print the page for some reason.

So, 2 questions. Is there a way to make it stop that, and is there a way to just run it from the command line, or without all of the fancy mouse stuff? Essentially as --no-windows?

Thanks!

Comment: This site is OS-agnostic. What gave you the impression that it was otherwise?

Comment: As evidenced by the thousands of questions tagged windows, @Dennis is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste?

If so, it's probably in [cua-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode).

Try adding

```
(cua-mode nil)
```

to his `.emacs` file, or disable CUA mode in the Options menu.

Of you could disable just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> by adding something like this in `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key "\C-p" 'previous-line)
```

And if none of that works, try typing this:

```
M-x describe-key <Ctrl><P>
```

where `M-x` means press Alt and x and

means press Ctrl and p.

It will say "It is bound to print-buffer" or "It is bound to ps-print-buffer-with-faces" or similar.  Then Google for Windows Emacs print-buffer, or whatever it is bound to.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but CUA is definitely disabled, I'll try adding the set-key line to the pref file.